# Detecting Youtube video state from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, youtube

Is there a way of detecting when a Youtube Video has finished playing from JavaScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure can - using the [javascript API for youtube](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Events)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able listen to the onStateChange event.

Check out the [API Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Events)